# Draw angle line over an image - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Why the angle line I draw is not the correct one. instead of the 45 deg I get the 315?

Script:

```
clc;
clear;
url='http://clipart-library.com/images/Bcgrakezi.png';
I = imread(url);
imshow(I);
hold on;

[y1,x1,z1] = size(I);
cy=y1/2;
cx=x1/2;

sz = 50;
scatter(cx,cy,sz,'d')

lineLength = 250;
angle = 45;
xAngleLine(1) = cx;
yAngleLine(1) = cy;
xAngleLine(2) = xAngleLine(1) + lineLength * cosd(angle);
yAngleLine(2) = yAngleLine(1) + lineLength * sind(angle);
plot(xAngleLine, yAngleLine,'g','LineWidth',5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When showing images, such as with [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) or [`image`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html), MATLAB inverts the y axis. This is so the first row of the image data (lowest row index) appears at the top of the plot. To account for this, you therefore need to flip the sign in the second-to-last line of code to a negative:

```
yAngleLine(2) = yAngleLine(1) - lineLength * sind(angle);
```

Comment: if I use cy = -y1/2 I don't get a line plot.

Comment: It seems we posted at the same time! Nice that you've got a solution there as well. I'm too literal in answering the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

`imshow` turns the y-axis up-side down. You can see this with:

```
get(gca,'YDir')
```

Which will say either `'normal'` (y-axis ticks increase upwards), or `'reverse'` (y-axis ticks increase downwards). In your case you'll see `'reverse'`.

You can also do

```
axis on
```

to see the tick marks and values.